# Coldfusion 10 ORM "Error while resolving the relationship"

Tags: hibernate, orm, coldfusion, hibernate-mapping, coldfusion-10

I've had an ORM application working for two years now local on my laptop for dev purposes and the ORM mappings have been working very well.  The app was originally created in CF9 but my local CF was upgraded to 10 shortly after the release of CF10.  Since that time I have a lot of hours doing additional development on this application.  The other day, based on a migration, I had to change some of the directory paths of the application.  After changing all of my mappings within CF and the application I went to boot up the application again and I got this gem:

> Error while resolving the relationship SpeakerEvalQuestions in cfc com.client.model.sessions. Check the column mapping for this property.

*Please ignore my poor judgement in naming one of my orm objects "sessions".

The path changed from `\web\sites\thesite\` to `\web\sites\thesite\www\`

/com is a CF mapping to `\web\sites\thesite\www\com` now

Here is tidbits from the CFC's:

```
<cfcomponent output="false" persistent="true" table="tblSessions">

<cfproperty
    name="sessionID"
    fieldtype="id"
    type="numeric"
    sqltype="int"
    generator="identity" />

<cfproperty
    name="ses_key"
    type="string"
    sqltype="varchar(40)" />

<cfproperty
    name="sessionTitle"
    type="string"
    sqltype="varchar(250)" />

<cfproperty
    name="day1Start"
    ormtype="timestamp"
    sqltype="datetime" />

<cfproperty
    name="day1End"
    ormtype="timestamp"
    sqltype="datetime" />

<cfproperty
    name="day2Start"
    ormtype="timestamp"
    sqltype="datetime" />

<cfproperty
    name="day2End"
    ormtype="timestamp"
    sqltype="datetime" />

<cfproperty
    name="defaultCreditValue"
    type="numeric"
    sqltype="decimal(10,5)" />

<cfproperty
    name="sessionCode"
    type="string"
    sqltype="varchar(max)" />


<cfproperty 
    name="dateAdded" 
    fieldtype="column" 
    ormtype="timestamp"
    sqltype="datetime" 
    dbDefault="GETDATE()"
    insert="true" 
    update="false"  />


<cfproperty
    name="SpeakerEvalQuestions"
    singularname="SpeakerEvalQuestion"
    fieldtype="many-to-many" 
    cfc="SpeakerEvalQuestions"
    inversejoincolum="speakerEvalQuestionID"
    fkcolumn="sessionID"
    lazy="extra"
    orderby="sortOrder asc"
    linktable="tblSpeakerEvalQs_Sessions"
    type="array" />


</cfcomponent>
```

AND

```
<cfcomponent output="false" persistent="true" table="tblSpeakerEvalQuestions">

<cfproperty
    name="speakerEvalQuestionID"
    fieldtype="id"
    type="numeric"
    generator="identity" />

<cfproperty
    name="question"
    type="string"
    sqltype="varchar(200)" />

<cfproperty
    name="scaleStartValue"
    type="numeric"
    sqltype="smallInt" />

<cfproperty
    name="scaleEndValue"
    type="numeric"
    sqltype="smallInt" />

<cfproperty
    name="sortOrder"
    type="numeric"
    sqltype="smallInt" />

<cfproperty
    name="display"
    type="numeric"
    sqltype="smallInt" />

<cfproperty 
    name="dateAdded" 
    fieldtype="column" 
    type="date"
    sqltype="datetime" 
    dbDefault="GETDATE()"
    insert="true" 
    update="false"  />


<cfproperty
    name="sessions"
    singularname="session"
    fieldtype="many-to-many" 
    CFC="sessions"
    fkcolumn="speakerEvalQuestionID"
    inversejoincolumn="sessionID"
    lazy="extra"
    orderby="day1start asc"
    linktable="tblSpeakerEvalQs_Sessions" />

</cfcomponent>
```

If I comment out the `SpeakerEvalQuestions` property from the sessions.cfc then the application boots and of course part of it doesn't work.  But that at least confirms that its this one property and not just the first in a long change of properties that are not going to work.

Again, this was working great until i had to change the paths.  Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: I know that there is some case sensitivity with CF10/Tomcat now, so make sure your case matches the cfc's case.

Comment: I did look at that as a possibility but didn't seem to be the answer.

Comment: I have given up on solving this and instead tried to boot up a new CF instance.  Booting it up in that new instance worked like a charm.  I have only mild curiosity with what happened under the old instance.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any of the caching options in CF Administrator turned on? If so, turn them off, or clear the cache.